# How to let second select put data according to first option

Tags: json, vue.js, select, vue-cli

I try to when I choose the first select and second select will according to the first option and put data into second select

It can put the data into first select but the second select still can't run

I think maybe my emit does't work but I still can't solve it
What the problem

This my App.vue

```
<template>
       <test
       :cities="cities"
       :areas="areas"
       @input="cityidx"
       ></test>
</template>

<script>
    import test from '@/components/SelectBoxTest.vue';
    import datalist from '@/assets/data.json';
    
    export default {
        name:'App',
        components: {
            test,
            Map,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                cityidx : 0,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            cities(){
                return datalist
            },
            areas(){
                return datalist[this.cityidx].AreaList
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my SelectBoxTest.vue

```
<template>
    <!--CitySelect-->
    <div>
        <select id="countryselect" class="text-center" v-model="cityselect">
            <option 
            v-for="(city , idx) of cities" 
            :key="city.text"
            :value="idx">{{city.CityEngName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--AreaSelect-->
    <div>
        <select id="areaselect" class="text-center" v-model="areaselect">
            <option
            v-for="area of areas"
            :key="area.text"
            >{{area.AreaEngName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    
    export default {
        name:'test',
        props:{
            'cities': {
                type: Array
            },
            'areas': {
                type: Array
            },
            'cityidx': {
                type: Number
            },
        },
        data(){
            return{
                cityselect: 0,
                areaselect: 0,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            update: {
                get(){
                    return this.cityselect
                },
                set(value){
                    this.$emit('input',value)
                }
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

The part of json

```
[
   {
      "CityEngName":"Taipei City",
      "AreaList":[
         {
            "ZipCode":"100",
            "AreaEngName":"Zhongzheng Dist."
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "CityEngName":"Keelung City",
      "AreaList":[
         {
            "ZipCode":"200",
            "AreaEngName":"Ren’ai Dist."
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

### Edit：1

After I try the new code , it can work by I want

But I meet an another problem is I need to choose the same option twice the select will change

What the bug of it

Thanks a lot

This Code of New App.vue

```
<template>
       <test
       :cities="cities"
       :areas="areas"
       v-model:current-city = "cityidx"
       v-model:current-area = "areaidx"
       ></test>
</template>
<script>
    import test from '@/components/SelectBoxTest.vue';
    
    export default {
        name:'App',
        components: {
            test,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                cityidx: 0,
                areaidx: 0
            }
        },
        computed: {
            cities(){
                return datalist
            },
            areas(){
                return datalist[this.cityidx].AreaList
            }   
        },
    }   
</script>
```

And SelectBoxTest.vue

```
<template>
    <!--CitySelect-->
    <div>
        <select v-model="cityselect">
            <option 
            v-for="(city , idx) of cities" 
            :key="idx"
            :value="idx">{{city.CityEngName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--AreaSelect-->
    <div>
        <select v-model="areaselect">
            <option
            v-for="(area , idx) of areas"
            :key="idx"
            :value="idx">{{area.AreaEngName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'test',
        props:{
            'cityidx': {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            'areaidx': {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            'cities': {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            'areas': {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
        },
        computed: {
            cityselect: {
                get(){
                    return this.cityidx;
                },
                set(val){
                    this.$emit('update:current-city' , val);
                }
            },
            areaselect: {
                get(){
                    return this.areaidx;
                },
                set(val){
                    this.$emit('update:current-area' , val);
                }
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedCity" name="city">
    <option v-for="city in cities" :key="city.id" :value="city.id">{{ city.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="selectedArea" name="area">
    <option v-for="area in areas" :key="area.id" :value="area.id">{{ area.name }}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'SelectCityArea',
  props:
  {
    currentCity:
    {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    currentArea:
    {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    cities:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    areas:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:current-city', 'update:current-area'],
  computed:
  {
    selectedCity:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.currentCity;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:current-city', val);
      }
    },
    selectedArea:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.currentArea;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:current-area', val);
      }
    },
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```html
<template>
  <SelectCityArea v-model:current-city="myCity" v-model:current-area="myArea" :cities="cityList" :areas="areaList" />
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  data()
  {
    return {
      myCity: null,
      myArea: null,
    }
  },
  computed:
  {
    cityList()
    {
      return [
        { id: 1, name: 'Paris' },
        { id: 2, name: 'New York' },
      ]
    },
    areaList()
    {
      return [
        { id: 3, name: 'Europe' },
        { id: 4, name: 'North America' },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Working example below:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
createApp({
    components:
    {
      SelectCityArea:
      {
      template: `<label>City: <select v-model="selectedCity" name="city" class="space">
    <option v-for="city in cities" :key="city.id" :value="city.id">{{ city.name }}</option>
  </select></label>
  <label>Area: <select v-model="selectedArea" name="area" class="space">
    <option v-for="area in areas" :key="area.id" :value="area.id">{{ area.name }}</option>
  </select></label>`,
  props:
  {
    currentCity:
    {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    currentArea:
    {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: null
    },
    cities:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    areas:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:current-city', 'update:current-area'],
  computed:
  {
    selectedCity:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.currentCity;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:current-city', val);
      }
    },
    selectedArea:
    {
      get()
      {
        return this.currentArea;
      },
      set(val)
      {
        this.$emit('update:current-area', val);
      }
    },
  },
      }
    },
    template: `<SelectCityArea v-model:current-city="myCity" v-model:current-area="myArea" :cities="cityList" :areas="areaList"></SelectCityArea><div class="space">City: {{ myCity }}</div><div class="space">Area: {{ myArea }}</div>`,
    data()
    {
      return {
        myCity: null,
        myArea: null,
      };
    },  
    computed:
  {
    cityList()
    {
      return [
        { id: 1, name: 'Paris' },
        { id: 2, name: 'New York' },
      ]
    },
    areaList()
    {
      return [
        { id: 3, name: 'Europe' },
        { id: 4, name: 'North America' },
      ]
    }
  },
  }).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<style>
.space
{
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I try it on my project but the second select still doesn't have data

Comment: Oh！I try your way and revise some code.It can run by my way!!Thanks for your inspiration！

Comment: I meet another problem I edit the problem on top

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what your new issue is.

Comment: When I choose the option but the select value doesn't change,I need to choose the same option twice and the value will change, I update new code in the edit

Comment: If you run the example snippet - you will notice that selecting a city or area actually updates the binded variable.